# Repackage UWP appx with different AppIds

Tags: windows, uwp

I am working on windows 10 UWP app. I am able to create an Appx file using VS2015, with an App Id com.test.app1. Is it possible to repackage the appx with a different App Id  ( com.test.app2) using the command line. We can resign ipa in iOS. Please let me know if this is possible on UWP.

Comment: What did you mean about the 'App Id'? In other word, how did you change the 'App Id' in your UWP project? And did you want to create different app packages to publish to windows store?

Comment: I am sideloading and not published to windows tore. Application Id can be changed from the manifest file. My requirement is to re-sign this appx file. The re-signed appx will point to new application Id say ( com.test.app2). Please let me know if this is possible

Comment: If you want to re-sign the appx file, you would need to change the publisher, not application Id. It should be the same with the certificate when you sign it.